# Powershell: adding an element from an array to another array

Tags: arrays, powershell, element

I am trying to add elements to array for filtering. after it goes through the loop the first time
I receive "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'."

I have tried several methods to try and figure this out.

```
$JsonDB = Get-Content 'Q:\Technology\1AA\HardwareCollection.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach($client in $JsonDB)
        {
            if($client.HRSeparation -eq "No")
                {
                    $ClientNotHRSeparated += $client
                }
            else
                {
                    $ClientHRSeparated += $client
                }
        }
$JsonDB
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `+=` is entirely dependent on the left-hand side operand. On the first assignment, the value of `$ClientNotHRSeparated` is `$null`, so the resulting operation is:

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated = $null + $someCustomPSObject
```

Which PowerShell evaluates as just:

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated = $someObject
```

On the second assigment, `$ClientNotHRSeparated` is no longer `$null`, and PowerShell instead of tries to identify an overload for `+` that works on two operands of type `[PSObject]`, which is where it fails.

If you want `+=` to perform array addition, define the two array variables ahead of time with an assignment of a resizable array (use the `@()` array subexpression operator):

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated = @()
$ClientHRSeparated = @()

$JsonDB = Get-Content 'Q:\Technology\1AA\HardwareCollection.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($client in $JsonDB) {
    if ($client.HRSeparation -eq "No") {
        $ClientNotHRSeparated += $client
    }
    else {
        $ClientHRSeparated += $client
    }
}
$JsonDB
```

Now `+=` is unambiguous both the first time and subsequently - the left-hand side operand is an array in either case.

---

As an alternative to looping through the whole collection manually, consider using the `.Where()` extension method in `Split` mode:

```
$JsonDB = Get-Content 'Q:\Technology\1AA\HardwareCollection.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

$ClientNotHRSeparated, $ClientHRSeparated = @($JsonDB).Where({$_.HRSeparation -eq 'No'}, 'Split')
```

Much faster and more concise :-)

Comment: Wow thanks for the lesson and the more efficient route this is fantastic and works perfectly!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`ConvertFrom-Json` parses a JSON string into PSObject(s).
Since you did not define `$ClientNotHRSeparated` and `$ClientHRSeparated` anywhere, but immediately start adding ($client) objects to it, in the first iteration your variable `$ClientNotHRSeparated` will become that client object.
The next time you do `+=`, you're trying to add an object to another object which does not work.

Define the variables on top of the script, preferably as [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) object that has a `.Add()` method.

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$ClientHRSeparated = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
```

Then in your loop use that as

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated.Add($client)
# same for $ClientHRSeparated
```

P.S. Using a List is much faster/better that adding to a simple array (`@()`), because when you add items to an array (which has a fixed length) with `+=`, the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt in memory, consuming memory and processing time

Although this works, you don't need a loop at all. Just do:

```
$ClientNotHRSeparated = $JsonDB | Where-Object { $_.HRSeparation -eq "No" }
$ClientHRSeparated = $JsonDB | Where-Object { $_.HRSeparation -ne "No" }
```

<sup>The first line can be rewritten as `$JsonDB = Get-Content -Path 'Q:\Technology\1AA\HardwareCollection.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json`.

Switch `-Raw` makes the cmdlet read the content of the file as one single multilined string</sup>